# Как при использовании std::cin обнаружить несоответствие типа

Tags: c++, поток-ввода

Мне нужно сделать безопасный ввод данных. Имеется следующий код:

```
uint32_t n = 0;
vector<double> arr{};
cin.exceptions(istream::failbit | istream::badbit | istream::eofbit);
try {
    cin >> n; 
    double val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> val;
        arr.push_back(val);
    }
}
catch (istream::failure e) {
    cerr << "[error]" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}
```

Когда вводится всякая белиберда, то cin бросает исключение и всё хорошо. Но когда на этапе ввода n (которое без знаковое целое) вместо 10 вести -10 или 10.1, cin это нормально проглатывает и не чего не бросает. Как мне заставить cin воспринимать это как некорректный ввод?

Comment: поток не приводит типы, а читает их, если они есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если  вы ввели 10.1, то считывается цифра 10, а остальное остается в потоке, а не осуществляется приведение типов. Для ясности введите и оставшуюся сиволы, например в string и убедитесь в этом

```
uint32_t n = 0;
string s;     
cin >> n;
cin >> s;  
cout << n << endl << s; // n == 10, s == ".1"
```

Comment: Ситуация более-менее проясняется. Когда я ввожу "10.1" он хватает "10" и присваивает n, а ".1" он хватает как 0.1. Но кода я ввожу “-1”, он берёт тип uint32_t, ставит в первый бит значения 1 и поднимает знаковый бит. Но uint32_t не знаковый тип, поэтому там образуется огромное число из-за единицы в самом конце. Такое поведение некорректно, неужели в cin этого не предусмотрели? Как этого избежать?

Comment: вы хотите сказать, что если вы пытаетесь присваивать  одному типу другой тип, то виноват язык или компилятор?  Вы сами должны  программировать так, чтоб исключить некорректное поведение...  Языку неизвестны ваши пожелания, язык дает вам возможность  и инструменты делать так как вам захочется...